# Celery tasks running via crontab not received

Tags: python-3.x, cron, celery, celery-task

Celery is not receiving tasks that I have scheduled via the crontab.
Celery is running, and my celery.log logs

```
[2023-07-20 19:38:13,445: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0
[2023-07-20 19:38:13,447: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2023-07-20 19:38:14,453: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2023-07-20 19:38:14,461: INFO/MainProcess] celery@ip-hidden ready.
```

However, when I run my tasks via cronjobs (for ex.
`5 * * * * cd /home/user/folder && python3 -c 'from dispatcher.tasks import task; task.delay("task")'`
)

Nothing happens. Noting, that this celery instance is started by a batch script which runs via a cronjob. When I run this bash script myself, and then run the tasks myself, it works fine. It also works fine when I run the bash script myself, and then let the tasks run via crontab. It only doesn't work when both celery is started with crontab and my jobs are running via crontab.

Other information that may be useful:

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash    
if pgrep celery > /dev/null
         PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
then

    echo "celery is running"

else

    echo "celery stopped"

    cd /home/user/folder/folder && celery -A dispatcher worker --concurrency=4 --loglevel=info --logfile=/home/user/logfolder/celery.log

fi
```

Celery is definitely running, and when I manually run the bash script after the cronjob I also get alerted that 'celery is running'.

As seen from the log, Celery does not even receive the task. I can also prove that it doesn't run as these tasks create files, that are not being created. I know the cronjobs are running as I get emails with no errors logged.

Ignore folder names/hidden IPs/task names please, security is essential :D

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you running celery using crontab? It is not meant to be run like that.